# Google map not loading completly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

here is my code

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_auto'), mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('event_input_auto');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map
        });

        /*new added*/
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
            var location = map.getCenter();
            //new added
            placeMarker(location);
            displayLocation(location.lat(),location.lng());

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            zoomLevel = map.getZoom();      
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
            zoomLevel = map.getZoom()+1;
            if (zoomLevel == 20) {
                zoomLevel = 10;
            }
            map.setZoom(zoomLevel);

        });


        /*new added*/


        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            $('#map_holder').show();
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setCenter(location);
            });


            infowindow.close();
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
              map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }
            //alert(autocomplete.getBounds());
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                place.icon, new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
            marker.setIcon(image);
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
              address = [
                (place.address_components[0] &&
                 place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] &&
                 place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] &&
                 place.address_components[2].short_name || '')].join(' ');
            }

            infowindow.setContent('<div><b>' + place.name + '</b><br>' + address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
        // Autocomplete.
        var setupClickListener = function(id, types) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
          autocomplete.setTypes(types);
        });
        }

        setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
        //setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
        //setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function placeMarker(location) {    
    var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
    marker.setPosition(location);
}

function displayLocation(latitude,longitude){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
    var async = true;

    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var address = data.results[0];
        //document.write(address.formatted_address);
        document.getElementById("event_input_auto").value = address.formatted_address;
      }
    };
    request.send();
};


</script>

<input type="text" name="location" class="input-xxlarge required" id="event_input_auto" value="" />
<div id="map_holder" style="display: none;">
<div id="map_auto" style="height: 300px; width: 800px;" ></div>
</div>
```

Map loads completely when `#map_holder` is `display:block`

But i need to load map when `#map_holder` is `display:none`. this is my requirement.

What i have to do to load the map completely??

Comment: elaborate your requirement

Comment: Complete Map is not loading.

Comment: i mean what you want to do why u need display:none over display:block

Comment: 1. Initially, div for loading map should be hidden.
2. Once i type address, it should show the map and div should be display

Comment: okay so make an event like button click or keyUp so you can change its display value with jquery

Comment: please try this code first. Display none to display block is not my problem. Problem is map is not loading completely, only partial map is viewed. is there any way that when i type something in text input and click to autosuggested address, it loads complete map .

Comment: it sounds a bit rude that instead of trying what is suggested you answer to try your code first. It's you who should try debug your code or at least bring it down to the very problem.

Comment: my apology if I sound rude. i was just elaborating my problem.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle, because I tried your code and it works as expected

Comment: @alkis, is that you who answered about resize? I don't know why have you removed the answer. 

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
works out for me. that was the solution i was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> resize - Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div
>   changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize').

So try `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` after changing the display to block

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation resize - Developers should trigger this event on the map

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
       map.setCenter(location);
});
```

Add above code just below

```
$('#map_holder').show();
```

Comment: Didn't you have this? I answered it 20mins ago but I deleted because I saw that you had it already.

Comment: What i found is
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setCenter(location);
            });
was not working. 
Now i just used 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

instead.